# Flask SQLite query

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

This doesnt work. How can you get this to work?

```
        g.db.execute('update address set firstname=?,surname=?,email=?,mobile=? where contact_id = ?',\
                    [request.form['firstname'], request.form['surname'],\
                    request.form['email'], request.form['mobile'],[contact_id]])
```

Full Method:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:contact_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def contact_edit(contact_id):
    contact_id = str(contact_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        g.db.execute('update address set firstname=?,surname=?,email=?,mobile=? where contact_id = ?',\
                    [request.form['firstname'], request.form['surname'],\
                    request.form['email'], request.form['mobile'],[contact_id]])
        g.db.commit()
        flash('The contact was successfully edited')
        return redirect(url_for('contact_detail'))
    elif request.method != 'POST':
        cur = g.db.execute('select contact_id, surname, firstname, email, mobile\
                       from address where contact_id = ?', [contact_id])
        select = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('editcontact.html', select=select)
```

Comment: Please elaborate more.... and post at least working example. that `email?` syntaxt doesn't look correct..

Comment: Thanks, I changed that but basically it doesnt like the 5th parameter. [Contact_id]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the brackets around `contact_id`, like so:

```
g.db.execute('update address set firstname=?,surname=?,email=?,mobile=? where contact_id = ?',\
                (request.form['firstname'], request.form['surname'],\
                request.form['email'], request.form['mobile'],contact_id))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Came here searching how to pass multiple arguments go SQLite query. Thanks for the illustration! =)